# C++11 use-case for piecewise_construct of pair and tuple?

Tags: c++11, tuples, use-case, forwarding, piecewise

In [N3059](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3059.pdf) I found the description of **piecewise construction** of pairs (and tuples) (and it is in the new Standard).

But I can not see when I should use it. I found discussions about *emplace* and non-copyable entities, but when I tried it out, I could not create a case where I *need* `piecewiese_construct` or could see a performance benefit.

Example. I thought I need a class which is *non-copyable*, but *movebale* (required for forwarding):

```
struct NoCopy {
  NoCopy(int, int) {};
  NoCopy(const NoCopy&) = delete; // no copy
  NoCopy& operator=(const NoCopy&) = delete; // no assign
  NoCopy(NoCopy&&) {}; // please move
  NoCopy& operator=(NoCopy&&) {}; // please move-assign
};
```

I then sort-of expected that standard pair-construction would fail:

```
pair<NoCopy,NoCopy> x{ NoCopy{1,2}, NoCopy{2,3} }; // fine!
```

but it did not. Actually, this is what I'd expected anyway, because "moving stuff around" rather then copying it everywhere in the stdlib, is it should be.

Thus, I see no reason why I should have done this, or so:

```
pair<NoCopy,NoCopy> y(
    piecewise_construct,
    forward_as_tuple(1,2),
    forward_as_tuple(2,3)
); // also fine
```

- So, what's a the **usecase**?
- **How and when** do I use `piecewise_construct`?

Comment: Try also disabling the move constructor.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Not all types can be moved more efficiently than copied, and for some types it may make sense to even explicitly disable both copying and moving. Consider `std::array<int, BIGNUM>` as an an example of the former kind of a type.

The point with the `emplace` functions and `piecewise_construct` is that such a class can be constructed *in place*, without needing to create temporary instances to be moved or copied.

```
struct big {
    int data[100];
    big(int first, int second) : data{first, second} {
        // the rest of the array is presumably filled somehow as well
    }
};

std::pair<big, big> pair(piecewise_construct, {1,2}, {3,4});
```

Compare the above to `pair(big(1,2), big(3,4))` where two temporary `big` objects would have to be created and then copied - and moving does not help here at all! Similarly:

```
std::vector<big> vec;
vec.emplace_back(1,2);
```

The main use case for piecewise constructing a pair is emplacing elements into a `map` or an `unordered_map`:

```
std::map<int, big> map;
map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, /*key*/1, /*value*/{2,3});
```

Comment: You described that quite nicely, thanks. And thate quite what I thought, too. But `pair(piecewise_construct,...)` does not work if you **disable moving on the target class** (with `=delete`). I tried it with gcc-4.7.0 and *got a compile error*. reason: implementation of `pair`: <br> `template<class... _Args1, class... _Args2> pair(piecewise_construct_t, tuple<_Args1...> __first, tuple<_Args2...> __second) : first(__cons<first_type>(std::move(__first))), second(__cons<second_type>(std::move(__second))) { }` As you can see, a **move** is required. **emplace** does not seem to be used.

Comment: Ok, it seems that gcc-4.7.0 does not yet offer `map.emplace()`. But this still leaves my question about the `pair(piecewise_construct, {...},{...})`. Should this work with *non-copyable* **and** *non-movable* objects? From the formulation in the Std 20.3.2.(14) it might seem that way. Although "forwarding" is mehtioned, it seems to apply on the arguments of the constructors and not on the objects itself (where then a move could be needed?).

Comment: @towi : I think gcc-4.7.0+libstdc++ is non-compliant yet for pair constructor with piecewise_construct. Non-copyable and non-movable object should work and for example clang+libc++ give the right result. @JohannesD : I don't understand why you think map.emplace should work with piecewise_construct ? Every proposal that I'm aware of seem to imply that the usage of emplace should be `map.emplace(Key, ArgForValue...)`, so for example `map.emplace(/*key*/1, /*value*/ 2, 3);` (and that's how clang+libc++ behave)

Comment: about the example of `pair(big(1,2), big(3,4))`, it should be optimized by copy elision right? the constructed object `big(1, 2)` has no other reference name except the pair.

Comment: `map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, /*key*/1, /*value*/{2,3});` does not compile, instead it should be used `map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(1), std::forward_as_tuple(2,3));` as the appropriate constructor of `std::pair` is
`template< class... Args1, class... Args2 >
pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<Args1...> first_args, std::tuple<Args2...> second_args );`

Comment: `std::pair<big, big> pair(piecewise_construct, {1,2}, {3,4});` does not compiles too

Answer (score 1):

One power `piecewise_construct` has is to avoid bad conversions when doing overload resolution to construct objects.

Consider a `Foo` that has a weird set of constructor overloads:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    Foo(std::tuple<float, float>) { /* ... */ }
    Foo(int, double) { /* ... */ }
};

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, Foo> m1;
    std::pair<int, double> p1{1, 3.14};

    m1.emplace("Will call Foo(std::tuple<float, float>)",
               p1);

    m1.emplace("Will still call Foo(std::tuple<float, float>)",
               std::forward_as_tuple(2, 3.14));

    m1.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
               std::forward_as_tuple("Will call Foo(int, double)"),
               std::forward_as_tuple(3, 3.14));

    // Some care is required, though...
    m1.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
               std::forward_as_tuple("Will call Foo(std::tuple<float, float>)!"),
               std::forward_as_tuple(p1));
}
```